# Error Installing Support Package of Freescale FRDM-KL25Z in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I was trying to install `FRDM-KL25Z` Support Package and following the official website instructions. But I was prompted with an error showing:

> File Dir does not contain archives for third-party software used by
>   the support package.

I select the "Install from Internet" option but it still doesn't work. Please Help. Thanks.

[image: Attached Image]

Answer (score 0):

contacted the technical support of Mathworks and it seems like there's a problem with the installation package. Developer has fixed it.